# Animate Layout Changes on flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have created a form in flutter and I want to hide some components with a smooth layout shrinking or expanding animation similar to LinearLayout when animatelayoutchanges is set to true.

Update:
To make my question more clear. I kind of wanted to do like in this gif attachment below but on flutter. I am trying to hide some components and I want the remaining visible components to smoothly transition to its new position from their previous ones.
I'm new to flutter so I really don't know much about animating components.

[animatelayoutchanges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgq2Z.gif)

Comment: Can you share your findings regarding this issue? hove you done enough search for this solution? please share what you have tried and what are results

Comment: The only similar solution I've found is AnimatedContainer but still it leaves a border line even after its height is 0.

Answer (score -1):

check for AnimatedContainer:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html

set height on animatelayoutchanges false 0 else give it the height you want

```
AnimatedContainer(
height: animatelayoutchanges ? 300 : 0,
duration: Duration(seconds: 1)
)
```

Comment: The animations are slow and it also leaves a line which i dont want. Any way to completely hide it?

Comment: 1- Animation will be faster on the APK. 2- make color transparent if animatelayoutchanges is false